# Restarting an EC2 instance on the instance that is to be restarted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running through a loop with a PHP script that's on AWS instance. From my experiences with AWS, as soon as the instance is stopped, all of the code that's in the process of being executed is stopped. What I have is this:

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

$instance_id = 'instance_id';
$creds = array('key' => 'key', 
                'secret' => 'secret', 
                'region' => 'us-west-2');
$client = Ec2Client::factory($creds);
$instance = array('InstanceIds' => array($instance_id), 'DryRun' => false);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    // Execute irrelevant code
    // .....

    $result = $client->stopInstances($instance);
    sleep(300);
    $result = $client->startInstances($instance);
}
?>
```

So, my question is this: Once the instance is stopped, everything that is written after that will not be executed since the instance will be stopped, right? The loop will not continue on to the next iteration, right? If so, then how could I get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the stopinstances api, EC2 will start shutting down your instance (and the OS inside the instance will kill running processes as part of it)

There's no guarantee exactly how long this will take, although in my experience you'll rarely get more than a couple of seconds, so that `sleep(300)` pretty much guarantees that the call to `stopInstances` is the last thing that your code will do.

There's nothing you can do about this other than not stopping the instance you are running on. To that end you can query the instance metadata service to find out what the id of the instance running your code is. You can get this data by making a request to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start an instance that is Stopped from the same instance. You can keep an additional (external) server either on EC2 or otherwise to control automatic shutdowns/startups.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from @TJ-'s answers...
You can check to see if the instance is stopped and then continue with your code
`$client->waitUntil('InstanceStopped', array('InstanceIds' => $instanceId));`
But you have to run this from a different instance than the one being terminated.